# Merge statement error in Databricks community edition: ParseException: extraneous input

Tags: sql, merge, databricks

I am getting below error while using merge statement in Databricks:

```sql
 MERGE INTO t1
 USING
  t2
 ON
  t1.[c1] = t2.[c1]
 AND
  t1.[c2] <> t2.[c2]
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
 SET   t1.[c1] = t2.[c2]
```

Error:

> Error in SQL statement: ParseException: extraneous input

Could you please help on this?

Answer (score 0):

```
MERGE database.schema.tablename as t1 
USING <the Query you want to run or the database.schema.tablename>  as t2 
ON (t1.[c1] = t2.[c1] AND t1.[c2] != t2.[c2])
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t1.[c1] = t2.[c2]
```

try the above recomendation

Comment: there is no database..just we loaded csv files to table